# What is the differences between DotFit bars and PowerBars?

Tags: nutrition, protein

I am wondering if anyone can tell me the difference between [DotFit](http://www.dotfit.com/Iced_Peanut_Butter_Delight-pid-1400.html) bars and [PowerBars](http://www.powerbar.ca/products/209/powerbar-triple-threat-bar.aspx)?

The gym I go to sell these bars but in supermarkets I see powerbars and not sure if they have different purposes or are the same thing but just different brands.

My trainer has recommend that in between meals that I eat a "dotfit bar" between meals but as I said the gym I work out only sells "dotfit bars".

Comment: How about you read the labels?

Comment: The difference is your trainer probably has shares in Dotfit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at what the bars contain, there are (as in all food) three main sources of energy: fat, carbohydrates and protein.

The two bars linked have similar composition when it comes to this, so unless you are really measuring your other intake during the day, the difference is negligible.

If looking at bars more in general, there are a few differences to look for, depending on why you want to eat the bar:

- "Energy bar": Usually quite rich in carbohydrates, advertised for eating before/during workouts.
- "Recovery bar": These have a bit more protein in them, usually good post-workout (especially as a quick source of protein after strength training)
- "Fitness bar": More or less meant to make you less hungry in as few calories as possible. More for weight-loss than actual fitness.

Comment: Thanks. What I am getting at is my trainer said I should have them(dot fit bars) in between as a snack but at they cost $2-$3 a bar that can get very expensive. So when I saw those bars for $1 I started wondering if they would achieve the same effect.

Comment: You'll get about the same amount of energy from a banana and a glass of milk (~3 dl). The bars, they are more or less the same and will therefore give the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your trainer is recommending them because he has to. I worked for gym that required me to sell 200 dollars of dot fit bars in order for me to reach my goal, failure to do so can result in termination. 
I wouldn't recommend dot fit to anyone, there are many better products out there.
Just make sure your following your recommended caloric intake and getting your recommended amount of protein